# Global/window assignment or console imports failure

Tags: stealjs, donejs

I fail to either set global or window property or require/import within browser console, which makes live testing impossible. I avoid running this code in SSR with platform.isNode condition.

Comment: Is this a question about DoneJS or StealJS?

Comment: donejs incorporates stealjs, and is what I'm using. I can't tell whose fault this specifically is.

Comment: Is there a specific error you’re seeing or example of what’s not working that you can show?

Comment: Never mind, there's another bug in a way of window assignment working. Using platform package to avoid SSR error works.